# Rails Model scope chaining based on dynamic scope name list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have some model

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  scope :opened, -> { where(status: 'open') }
  scope :closed, -> { where(status: 'closed') }
  scope :colored, -> { where.not(color: nil) }
  # etc
end
```

I can call scope chains like

```
MyModel.opened.colored
MyModel.send('opened').send('colored')
```

But how can I make scope chaining based on dynamic scope token list? I mean

```
scopes = ['opened', 'colored', ...]
```

The list may be very long and I need some general solution to do it as simple as possible, like `MyModel.send_list(scopes)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More as result of scope, you can add like,

```
scope :send_list, -> (*scopes) { scopes.inject(self) { |out, scope| out.send(scope) } }
```

send this like `YourModel.send_list(*scopes)`